# Synchronized methods and object locks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

From what I read and understood, every object has lock that takes place when it is trying to access a synchronized method.
Heres my code (in 2 different class files):

```
public class test {

 public synchronized void inc1( String who ) {

         for( int i = 0 ; i < 1500 ; i++ )
             System.out.println( who+": "+i );
 }
}



public class testsyn implements Runnable {

    test k = new test( );

    public static void main( String[ ] args )
    {

        new Thread( new testsyn( ) ).start( );

        new testsyn( ).doStuff( );

    }

    public void doStuff( ) { k.inc1( "Main" ); }

    public void run( )
    {
        k.inc1( "Thread" );
    }
}
```

So let's say that the first line of my output is:
"Main : 0".
that means that the main thread has acquired the key for the test object named 'k', right?
than how is it possible that the other thread i created is able to get inside the "inc1" method and print output before the main thread has finished with it?

I noticed that this issue occurs in this specific pattern but if i would have made 'k' static and wrote this instead (in testsyn class):

```
public class testsyn implements Runnable {

    static test k = new test( );

    public static void main( String[ ] args )
    {

        new Thread( new testsyn( ) ).start( );

        k.inc1( "Main" );

    }


    public void run( )
    {
        k.inc1( "Thread" );
    }
}
```

This would have worked the way I expected, and there wouldn't have been a collision between the output. For exmaple, if the main thread has entered the synchronized method first, than the other thread would have to wait until the main thread finished with that method.

The question I am asking here is how this change affected the behavior of the program? and why?

Comment: Since you don't show examples of your unexpected output, it''s difficult to see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `synchronized` keyword is used to obtain the lock; the lock is associated with an object instance. You have two instances of the `test` class; one given to each thread. So there is no contention. When the field `k` is static, then there is one instance shared among the threads.

Comment: Oh! i guess i haven't thought about it that way. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So let's say that the first line of my output is: "Main : 0". that
>   means that the main thread has acquired the key for the test object
>   named 'k', right? than how is it possible that the other thread i
>   created is able to get inside the "inc1" method and print output
>   before the main thread has finished with it?

You write "the test object named 'k'" as if there were only one.  In your example, `k` is an instance variable of class `testsyn`, so each instance has its own.  They refer to different objects, each with its own monitor.  A thread executing a synchronized instance method of one of those objects does not, therefore, prevent another thread from executing a synchronized instance method of the other.

> if i would have made 'k' static [...]  there wouldn't have been a collision between the output.

Yes.  `static` variables belong to the class in which they are declared.  They are shared by all instances.  A static `k`, having been initialized before `main()` runs and not thereafter being modified, is shared by both your threads.  Since they are both trying to run a synchronized method *of the same object*, one must wait until the other finishes.